# Why can't CakePHP 4 CLI connect to MySQL database via PDO?

Tags: mysql, pdo, php-7.4, cakephp-4.x

I'm using CakePHP 4 on a Linux Mint cinnamon installation with the LAMPP stack. I have a database with users and all chef hats of PHP are green. The application is also able to fetch data from my database when running in the browser.

I want to bake my users model/controller/views:

```
bin/cake bake all users
```

This returns the following error:

```
Exception: Connection to Mysql could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
In [/opt/lampp/htdocs/tgi-flydays-4/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php, line 107]
```

It looks like connecting to the database via PDO is not working:

```
 99  try {
100      $connection = new PDO(
101          $dsn,
102          $config['username'] ?: null,
103          $config['password'] ?: null,
104          $config['flags']
105      );
106  } catch (PDOException $e) {
107      throw new MissingConnectionException(
108          [
109              'driver' => App::shortName(static::class, 'Database/Driver'),
110              'reason' => $e->getMessage(),
111          ],
112          null,
113          $e
114      );
115  }
```

I have the database connection details correctly filled in in `app_local.php` (as said: running the application in the browser works fine with the database).

I installed `php7.4_pdo_mysql` and `php7.4-mysql`, running `php -m` returns the following:

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

`php -i` returns (amongst others):

```
PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 7.4.5
```

I also tried the following solutions:

- [CakePHP 3 is NOT able to connect to the database due to a missing PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403450/cakephp-3-is-not-able-to-connect-to-the-database-due-to-a-missing-php-extension)
- [PHP 7 RC3: How to install missing MySQL PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728860/php-7-rc3-how-to-install-missing-mysql-pdo)
- https://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/pdo-installation.php
- [Can't get going with MySQL in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574905/cant-get-going-with-mysql-in-cakephp)
- [PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @Your Common Sense I even mentioned that I already read and applied the information in the quation you say is similar to mine.

Comment: The problem is exactly the same. It means the question is a duplicate.

Comment: this is not the same problem. error message is the same, but the linked question is not a part of the solution for cakephp.